# Increasing memory of Samsung Galaxy XCover 3

Tags: samsung, internal-storage

Having Samsung Galaxy XCover 3 (8GB internal memory) and 64GB SD card, what is the best way to use the card?

Apparently you can not save apps to SD card, just a part of it, and it has to be visible, because some apps are not visible. For example app "Znakujte s námi" shows to take only 14 MB but it takes 700 MB, so if you are able to root phone (How to root Samsung Galaxy XCover 3 is question too.), Link2SD will not see it as 700 MB app.

Is it even possible to use effectively card for this type of phone?

Fot me it seems unrootable now - How to root it?

If it is possible to root it, how to move apps to SD if they look like that they are taking less space than they really does?

Comment: If anyone would like to turn on the Xcover 3 VE Adoptable Storage without root - here are the tips: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VDLOAzWwd-M

Answer (score 0):

Not all apps can be moved to SD card. Those that can be moved, you can do so from the Settings -> Apps listing for your device. Alternatively there are several apps that help you move several apps in one go. The best way to use your SD card is to use it for all media. Move all your media files from the Internal Memory to SD Card. Also change your camera apps settings to use the SD card for storage as the default would be to store it in the internal memory. Hope this helps.